# Was bedeutet „objektgeeignet“?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, technical-terminology

Kann mir jemand sagen, was „objektgeeignet“ bedeutet? Ich habe dieses Wort aus einer Produktbeschreibung für ein Einmalöl-Wachs:

> Mit nur einem Auftrag wird eine geölte und gleichzeitig gewachste Holzoberfläche in hervorragender Qualität und Beständigkeit erreicht. Es ist **objektgeeignet**, lösemittelfrei und läßt sich einfach mit der Rolle auftragen. Es ist für unbehandeltes oder vorgeöltes Holz im Möbel- oder Fußbodenbereich geeignet.

Comment: „geeignet zur Anwendung auf Objekten“ – generischer geht’s kaum. Man findet aber auch einige Treffer zu dem Wort, obwohl es eher konstruiert und ungebräuchlich scheint.

Comment: @dakab "konstruiert" ist das Wort nicht - Es ist ein Fachbegriff, wie aus den Antworten zu entnehmen ist, und daher dementsprechend selten außerhalb des falchlichen Bereiches verwendet.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Objekteignung* ist ein Fachbegriff, der hauptsächlich im Zusammenhang mit Inneneinrichtung (Bodenbeläge, Möbel, Tapeten, Türgriffe usw.) verwendet wird. Der Ausdruck *objektgeeignet* beschreibt dabei die Beanspruchungsklasse der Einrichtungsgegenstände. Die erforderliche Beanspruchungsklasse hängt von der Nutzungsart ab. Man unterscheidet dabei gewöhnlich in erster Näherung zwischen *Wohnbereich, Objektbereich* und *Industriebereich.*

Als *Objekte* werden dabei gewerblich oder öffentlich genutzte Räume bezeichnet (z. B. Kaufhäuser, Hotelzimmer usw.). Ein *objektgeeigneter* Einrichtungsgegenstand ist also nicht nur für private Wohnbereiche, sondern auch für gewerblich oder öffentlich genutzte Räume, jedoch nicht für den Industriebereich geeignet.

Die genauen Anforderungen an die jeweiligen Einrichtungsgegenstände sind gewöhnlich in nationalen Normen (z. B. DIN) oder anderen technischen Regeln festgelegt.

Answer (score 8):

*Objektgeeignet* ist eine Eigenschaft eines Einrichtungs- oder Ausstattungsgegenstandes, die ihn als „geeignet für den Einsatz in öffentlich zugänglichen Bereichen“ – also z.B. öffentliche Gebäude, aber auch Geschäftsgebäuden wie Läden und Büros, somit „Objekten“ – auszeichnet.

Der Begriff wird von Innenausstattern und -Architekten verwendet, um solche Gegenstände von solchen, die zur „rein häuslichen“ Verwendung gedacht sind, abzuheben.

An z.B. Möbel, Vorhänge und Lampen werden im öffentlichen Bereich wesentlich höhere Ansprüche gestellt als im Privatbereich. Bei einer Möbelpolitur könnte ich mir vorstellen, dass z.B. sichergestellt ist, dass die Politur keine Rückstände auf den Möbeln hinterlässt, an denen sich ein Besucher eventuell die Hosen versauen könnte.

Außerhalb des Bereichs Innenarchitektur hört sich der Begriff zugegenbenermaßen ein bisschen unsinnig an und wird m.W. auch nicht verwendet.